# Error "Port 443 requires elevated privilege's"

Tags: node.js, express, http, https, tmux

I am running an express js server on tmux in a node lightsail instance and I am trying to host the server on port 443. How could I solve this? I've tried running tmux and npm start with sudo both individually and simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

I found out.
You first do the `whereis` command to find out where node is located. Then giving said elevated prilileges. Everything shown below:

```
user@server:~/$ whereis node
node: /usr/local/bin/node

user@server:~/$ sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/local/bin/node
```